# Elegant way to avoid differentiating between upper - and lowercase characters ? (preferable in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, string, char, uppercase, lowercase

Is there an elegant way to treat both lower- and uppercase characters the same ?

Something where

```
if (char == a)
```

Would return true regardless of char being `A` or `a`.

Comment: `if (char.toUpperCase() == "A")`

Comment: `char === "a" || char === "A"` is elegant enough IMO.

Comment: There is always `if (/^a$/i.test(char))`. Dunno if I would call it elegant though.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert it to uppercase or lowercase first:

```
if (char.toUpperCase() == "A") {...}
// Or
if (char.toLowerCase() == "a") {...}
```